# How to make a bool accessible across multiple .cs files

Tags: c#, winforms

Say have a bool called X in A.cs and I want to have an if statement in B.cs saying

```
if(X)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could make it static and call it as `if(A.X){}`

Comment: Just make it public and call it the way @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut said.

Comment: Another method is to create a singleton class.

Comment: do you have an object of type `A` in `B.cs` ?

Comment: You could pass the instance of `A` where you are setting/reading `X` to `B` and access it's member, just make sure `X` is public.

Comment: Note that within a project it does not matter what is in which file. All what matters is what is in which type (class, struct etc.) and which modifiers things have (public, private, static etc.). Btw.: please show us the declaration of `X`.

Comment: Try to be *less* abstract when asking beginner questions. You may learn something new, see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve variable sharing between classes. One form could be using static variable. A simple version using your example would be the following

```
public class A
{
    public static bool X = false;
 
    private void TestA()
    {
        // can use it directly as it's accessible directly
        if(X == true)
        {

        }
    }
}

public class B
{ 
    private void TestB()
    {
        // need to access the static variable inside A
        if(A.X == true)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Since the variable is static, only 1 instance exists. If either class modify the variable both will see the change.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to make any variable public throughout multiply CS files.
It really depends on what you want.

If you want a single value that is **NOT** object determined, for example, bool isPaused to check if the game is paused. An absolute variable.

Here's an example(Using a property):

```
public class Manager 
{
    private static bool x;

    public static X => x; // if you only need it for reading
    public static X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } // if you want both reading and writing

}


public class SomeOtherClass 
{
    public void SomeMethod() 
    {
        if(Manager.X)
            Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

However, if you ask me, constantly checking for a bool variable to exit a program is not an efficient method to exit it. I don't really know what you want to do with that but overall sounds kinda unnecessary. if you really want to exit a program instead of calling a function that calls the exit... just call the exit.

But either way, this is how you make a static variable that's available in several CS files.

If you want it to be object dependent (aka not static), just like it suggest, do the same thing without the word static in it, and instead of accessing it from the type, access it from an instance of said type.